# is there a way to screenshot or record chrome dev tools (the tool pane/s itself)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As per the title, I'd like to know if there is a way to screenshot (shortcut or otherwise) the dev tools panes, using chrome itself, or a chrome plugin as secondary preference.

Comment: Please try [WIN+Shift+S](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-snipping-tool-and-take-a-screenshot-a35ac9ff-4a58-24c9-3253-f12bac9f9d44)

Comment: No, not a native one. you will have to rely on the screenshot capability that comes from your OS or a third party program.

Comment: "Native" means built-in to. If you just want to know how to screenshot these and are open to using other tools, you'll want to remove that word from your title and question.

Comment: Indeed, I meant native to chrome. But removed ‘native’ in case it’s too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

"Native" means built-in to, as in, not relying on any 3rd party utilities. As such, your title and first paragraph disagree with your 2nd paragraph. Assuming you meant the 2nd bit...

You don't specify and OS, but Windows has the built-in "native" <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for screenshots.

Outside the built-in Windows tool, there are a plethora of screenshotting and screen recording tools. Personally I've liked [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/), but [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) is also a well respected tool in this space.

ShareX, at least, (and probably Greenshot too) allow you to record video of specific sections of the screen. You can set up hotkeys to trigger this, or right-click on the ShareX icon in your taskbar and choose the desired function, draw the window over the region you wish to record, and it begins recording.

Windows' Snip & Sketch and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> allows you to draw regions of the screen you wish to snip and don't simply snip the entire screen.

Apply these regions to the Dev Tools section of your browser, and you'll capture that image or video.

Comment: As a vivid user of Greenshot, I can deny that it does not contain a video recording portion. It has a great image editor build in though.

Comment: Greenshot doesn't record video? That surprises me. I don't know why I picked ShareX over GS several years back, especially when coworkers used GS. I guess I just picked the right one by accident. lol :)